# How to reduce polynomial?

Tags: interpolation, linear-algebra

I have some 4 polynomials  like this. these equation is made by `polyfit()` from   MATLAB tool.

```
eq1) 3.1734x^3 -5.8952x^2 +3.8194x -0.0377
eq2) 2.1489x^3 -3.9026x^2 +2.8169x -0.0160
eq3) 1.0796x^3 -1.9013x^2 +1.8500x +0.0008
eq4) x
```

Then I want to make these 4 polynomials to one polynomial But I don't know how to apply this concept to my 4 polynomials .

## Update :

Here is referencing.
$$f(x) = 3x^3 - 4x^4 + 3x -7$$
$$f(x) = 3x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x -1$$

[image]

Actually, I want to apply above concepts to in my case.

How can I get a $\left(H^TH\right)^{-1}H^Ty$ from above equations?

Comment: What is your y and H? Do you want to fit a polynomial to your data y?

Comment: @Oliver : I am referencing here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392818/how-can-i-use-left-inverse-to-fx-3x-format-equation/1392843?noredirect=1#comment2835591_1392843